# Why does this code overflow with Int -> Int?

Tags: haskell

I am using recursive calls to calc an exponent. It works to 2**63 and then zeros out. I assume I have some overflow. But I thought Haskell handled this.

I tried numbers until 64 and checked into Int.

```
power :: Int -> Int
power n = if n==0 then 1 else 2*power(n-1)
main = return()
```

In GHCI

```
1152921504606846976
*Main> power 70
0
*Main> power 65
0
*Main> power 64
0
*Main> power 63
-9223372036854775808
*Main> power 62
4611686018427387904
```

Comment: Haskell handles this with the `Integer` type for arbitrary sized integers, the `Int` is however a fixed word size integer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I assume I have some overflow. But I thought Haskell handled this.

It is indeed overflow, and Haskell has a type to handle integral numbers with arbitrary size: the [**`Integer`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Integer). You however use an [**`Int`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Int). As the documentation specifies, for an `Int`:

> **`data Int`**
>
> A **fixed-precision integer type** with at least the range `[-2^29 .. 2^29-1]`. The exact range for a given implementation can be determined by using `minBound` and `maxBound` from the `Bounded` class.

An `Int` thus has a fixed word size, and can overflow. You can use an `Integer` however that can represent an arbitrary number (well until the memory is exhausted).

If we thus change the definition to:

```
power :: Integer -> Integer
power 0 = 1
power n = 2 * power (n-1)
```

we indeed can calculate *2<sup>128</sup>*:

```
Prelude> power 128
340282366920938463463374607431768211456
```

Note that we can boost the performance of this `power` function with:

```
power :: Integral i => i -> Integer
power 0 = 1
power n | even n = b2 * b2
        | otherwise = 2 * b2 * b2
    where b2 = power (div n 2)
```

This holds since *b<sup>2 a</sup> = (b<sup>2)a</sup>*. If we thus assume that all the operations are in constant time, then this algorithm runs in *O(log p)*. This however does not completely hold, since `b2` can be quite large, and thus multiplying `b2` does not run in constant time.

Comment: What is this `p` in your answer? You mean `b2` again, right?